# How to flatten out tab key value pair text format file in a table where key is column and value is data for the cell

Tags: sql, oracle, key-value, transpose

I have a text file where 1 single row is split in multiple rows in key-value pair. The data looks like below:

1,800001348

2,IDEAL OPTION

27,Place of Service

39,IDEAL OPTION

400,123 MAIN STREET

400,Ste G

410,SEATTLE

420,Washington

423,BENTON

430,99336

and the whole block repeats again:
1,850000900

2,INVITAE CORPORATION

27,Place of Service

39,INVITAE CORPORATION

400,XYZ 1st AVENUE

410,SAN FRANCISCO

420,California

423,SAN FRANCISCO

430,94103

I have loaded this file in Oracle using SQL Loader. The integrity is maintained since I have a sequence number attached to all rows so I can traverse the table row by row and tell where the 1st row begins and ends.

KEY     VALUE               SEQNUM

1   800001348       1

2   IDEAL OPTION        2

27  Place of Service    3

39  IDEAL OPTION        4

400 123 MAIN Street     5

400 Ste G               6

410 KENNEWICK           7

420 Washington          8

423 BENTON              9

430 99336               10

1   850000900       11

2   INVITAE CORPORATION 12

27  Place of Service    13

39  INVITAE CORPORATION 14

400 XYZ 1st AVENUE      15

410 SAN FRANCISCO       16

420 California      17

423 SAN FRANCISCO       18

430 94103               19

```
select 
case when KEY = '1' then value else null end as FACILITY_ID,
case when KEY = '2' then value else null end as  Unknown_num,
case when KEY = '27' then value else null end as  TYPE_OF_LOCATION,
case when KEY = '39' then value else null end as  EXTERNAL_NAME,
case when KEY = '400' then value else null end as  ADDRESS,
case when KEY = '410' then value else null end as  CITY,
case when KEY = '420' then value else null end as  STATE,
case when KEY = '423' then value else null end as  COUNTY,
case when KEY = '430' then value else null end as  ZIP_CODE,
value,
SEQNUM from MDM_ODS.EAF_EPIC_IMPORT order by SEQNUM;
```

I get the transposed result  but as expected they are all on different rows and have a lot of nulls, any way to combine them to make them in 1 row?

FACILITY_ID UNKNOWN_NUM TYPE_OF_LOCATION EXTERNAL_NAME ADDRESS         CITY
800001348
        IDEAL OPTION
                Place of Service
                            IDEAL OPTION
                                      8514 W Gage Blvd
                                      Ste G 
                                                 KENNEWICK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this could work:

```
SELECT facility_id, unknown_num, type_of_location, external_name,
       address, city, state, county, zip_code
   FROM (
  SELECT key,
         value facility_id,
         LEAD(value, 1)  OVER (ORDER BY seqnum) unknown_num,
         LEAD(value, 2)  OVER (ORDER BY seqnum) type_of_location,
         LEAD(value, 3)  OVER (ORDER BY seqnum) external_name,
         LEAD(value, 4)  OVER (ORDER BY seqnum) address,
         LEAD(value, 5)  OVER (ORDER BY seqnum) city,
         LEAD(value, 6)  OVER (ORDER BY seqnum) state,
         LEAD(value, 7)  OVER (ORDER BY seqnum) county,
         LEAD(value, 8)  OVER (ORDER BY seqnum) zip_code
    FROM MDM_ODS.EAF_EPIC_IMPORT
    ORDER BY seqnum)
  WHERE key=1;
```

`LEAD(X, N) OVER (ORDER BY <sort-order>)`  means return the value of column "X" that is "N" number of rows ahead of the current row with the rows ordered by `<sort-order>`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
-- MANUAL DATA CREATION
WITH DATAA AS (
    SELECT
        1 KEY,
        '800001348' VALUE,
        1 SEQNUM
    FROM
        DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        2,
        'IDEAL OPTION',
        2
    FROM
        DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        27,
        'Place of Service',
        3
    FROM
        DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        39,
        'IDEAL OPTION',
        4
    FROM
        DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        400,
        '123 MAIN STREET',
        5
    FROM
        DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        400,
        'Ste G',
        6
    FROM
        DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        410,
        'SEATTLE',
        7
    FROM
        DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        420,
        'Washington',
        8
    FROM
        DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        423,
        'BENTON',
        9
    FROM
        DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        430,
        '99336',
        10
    FROM
        DUAL
--
--
    UNION ALL
--
--
    SELECT
        1 KEY,
        '850000900' VALUE,
        11 SEQNUM
    FROM
        DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        2,
        'INVITAE CORPORATION',
        12
    FROM
        DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        27,
        'Place of Service',
        13
    FROM
        DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        39,
        'INVITAE CORPORATION',
        14
    FROM
        DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        400,
        'XYZ 1st AVENUE',
        15
    FROM
        DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        410,
        'SAN FRANCISCO',
        16
    FROM
        DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        420,
        'California',
        17
    FROM
        DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        423,
        'SAN FRANCISCO',
        18
    FROM
        DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        430,
        '94103',
        19
    FROM
        DUAL
)
--
-- YOUR QUERY STARTS FROM HERE
--
SELECT
    MAX(CASE
        WHEN KEY = '1' THEN VALUE
    END) AS FACILITY_ID,
    MAX(CASE
        WHEN KEY = '2' THEN VALUE
    END) AS UNKNOWN_NUM,
    MAX(CASE
        WHEN KEY = '27' THEN VALUE
    END) AS TYPE_OF_LOCATION,
    MAX(CASE
        WHEN KEY = '39' THEN VALUE
    END) AS EXTERNAL_NAME,
    TRIM(',' FROM
        LISTAGG(CASE
            WHEN KEY = '400' THEN VALUE
        END, ',') WITHIN GROUP(
            ORDER BY
                SEQNUM
        )
    ) AS ADDRESS, -- ADDRESS HAS MORE THAN ONE RECORD IN THE FIRST GROUP OF VALUES
    MAX(CASE
        WHEN KEY = '410' THEN VALUE
    END) AS CITY,
    MAX(CASE
        WHEN KEY = '420' THEN VALUE
    END) AS STATE,
    MAX(CASE
        WHEN KEY = '423' THEN VALUE
    END) AS COUNTY,
    MAX(CASE
        WHEN KEY = '430' THEN VALUE
    END) AS ZIP_CODE
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            DATAA_ALL.KEY,
            DATAA_ALL.VALUE,
            DATAA_ALL.SEQNUM,
            COUNT(1) AS GRP_VAR
        FROM
            DATAA DATAA_ALL
            JOIN DATAA DATAA_FIRST ON ( DATAA_FIRST.KEY = 1
                                        AND DATAA_ALL.SEQNUM >= DATAA_FIRST.SEQNUM )
        GROUP BY
            DATAA_ALL.KEY,
            DATAA_ALL.VALUE,
            DATAA_ALL.SEQNUM
    )
GROUP BY
    GRP_VAR
```

**Output**
[image]

I have used `GRP_VAR` to partition the groups and then used the group functions.
Also, Wherever there are chances of having more than one records of the same attribute (Like address in the above example), You can use `LISTAGG` instead of `MAX`.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you have two problems:

1. Grouping the value-pairs by "record"..
2. Pivoting the rows to columns

I've created a [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a28d0/4/0) with a table like this, and I've added your sample data.

```
create table your_table_t(
   k    number
  ,v    varchar2(200)
  ,seq number
);
```

For the first problem, I have assumed that `key = 1` is your record ID. So the goal is to assign that ID to each value-pair that belongs to that record. For this, I've used a coalesce expression that will copy the value for key=1 onto each value-pair.

For the second part, I've simply used Oracle's `PIVOT` operator to pivot the rows into columns.

```
with identify_record as(
   select k,v
            ,coalesce(    decode(k,1,v,null)
                     ,lag(decode(k,1,v,null),1) ignore nulls over(order by seq)) as id
        from your_table_t a
)
select *    
  from identify_record pivot(
         max(v) for k in(1   as FACILITY_ID
                        ,2   as Unknown_num
                        ,27  as TYPE_OF_LOCATION
                        ,39  as EXTERNAL_NAME
                        ,400 as ADDRESS
                        ,410 as CITY
                        ,420 as STATE
                        ,423 as COUNTY
                        ,430 as ZIP_CODE                        
                        )
  );
```

You'll get the following output:

```
ID          FACILITY_ID    UNKNOWN_NUM             TYPE_OF_LOCATION     EXTERNAL_NAME           ADDRESS           CITY              STATE          COUNTY            ZIP_CODE
"800001348" "800001348"    "IDEAL OPTION"          "Place of Service"   "IDEAL OPTION"          "Ste G"           "KENNEWICK"       "Washington"   "BENTON"          "99336"
"850000900" "850000900"    "INVITAE CORPORATION"   "Place of Service"   "INVITAE CORPORATION"   "XYZ 1st AVENUE"  "SAN FRANCISCO"   "California"   "SAN FRANCISCO"   "94103"
```